Quantlib IndexManager
I am doing some research on how to leverage QuantLib for calculating XVAs in Python and I am now struggling to understand something. Basically, I would like to simulate n paths. Each one of the paths will need an instance of a Sonia index with a set of simulated rate fixings. Each set of fixings is different from the other. I seem to understand that every time I add a new set of fixings to the index (i.e. using the ql.Sonia().addFixings() method), these are added to all instances of the same index, conflicting with my objective. I also seem to understand that different sets of fixings can be added to the IndexManager using the setHistory method. This method requires a string name, so I managed to create n sets of fixings with different names - i.e. I can see all of them using the ql.IndexManager.instance().histories() function. Now my question is, in my n simulations how do I activate each instance of the index so that a different set of fixings is used?
Hope the question is clear!
Thank you
